# Bootstrap accordion allow multiple to open

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui-accordion

I have taken this accordion code from Bootstraps own source. But it doesn't collapse the others when I open a new one. Probably the question is already answered here, but I was unable to find it. Thanks for your help.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar">
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar">

        <div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
          <div class="accordion-group">
            <div class="accordion-heading">
              <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne">
                Collapsible Group Item #1
              </a>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body in collapse" style="height: auto;">
              <div class="accordion-inner">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="accordion-group">
            <div class="accordion-heading">
              <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo">
                Collapsible Group Item #2
              </a>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse" style="height: 0px;">
              <div class="accordion-inner">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="accordion-group">
            <div class="accordion-heading">
              <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseThree">
                Collapsible Group Item #3
              </a>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseThree" class="accordion-body collapse" style="height: 0px;">
              <div class="accordion-inner">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="body">
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Jorn said, you are using the wrong classes. Here is your example with the minimum changes...
Change

```
class="accordion-group"
```

to

```
class="panel panel-default"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g1tpwbsy/2/

And here is a more recent bootstrap accordion:
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion

Comment: Thanks.. Foolish me, I didn't realise I was taking an example from the deprecated site

Answer (score 1):

Your code will work as is *if* you switch Bootstrap versions. I just tested it locally with Bootstrap v2.3.2. You may need to download and deploy on premise rather than using a CDN.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using the wrong classes to indicate the accordion sections. 
According to the bootstrap docs they start with `panel-*` not `accordion-*`.
Just check out the working example at http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any aria parameters.
I've used the same example form bootstrap page, but there were aria parameters and it worked fine for me.

Look at the code on bootstrap page http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse